# Dynamically created checkbox in jquery mobile not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<div class="ui-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="reminder" id="reminder" checked="">
      <label for="reminder" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off ui-last-child">Reminder</label>
</div>
```

I am generating the above css and input checkbox on runtime via jquery however my checkbox isn't selecting could someone help me.

I have tried everything using jquery mobile and [nativedroid](http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/demo/forms.html)

[image]

Comment: How come label has type??

Comment: because i need to add css before that in case of checkbox so made that i can change it to some other identifier

Comment: I don't understand how a label can be of type checkbox...

Comment: have removed it doesn't really effect my outcome

Comment: @vini - now you're talking.

Comment: @vini: and how are you changing the checkbox value. using js to set it or expecting tap event to check the checkbox??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Will i have to handle that as well? when dynamically generating styles?

Comment: If you are trying to set the property from js then you need to refresh the object. are you looking for changing it through js??

Comment: nope i think my checkbox is getting selected just need to show it on the ui

Comment: <input> tag not closed it seems.

Comment: have closed it doesn't affect my output

Comment: what happens is  ui-checkbox-on and  ui-checkbox-off makes the difference in the ui will have to set it via jquery i think

Comment: Have solved this issue

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic checkboxes in jQuery Mobile, you need to initialize the widget either by calling `.checkboxradio()` on the input or `.enhanceWithin()` on the container, e.g.:

```
var chk = '<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0 ">Check me</label>';    
$("#dynCheck").empty().append(chk).enhanceWithin();
```

This assumes you have a container with id="dynCheck", and you want to empty it before adding the dynamic content.

```
<div id="dynCheck"></div>
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/xTdW6/)**

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating the above content? I think that's more relevant than the content itself. When creating and checking checkboxes via jQuery, you should use the `prop()` method to actually check the created boxes.

For example:

```
$('#reminder').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML markup just needs to define a checkbox wrapped in a label (or a label using the "for" attribute).  jQueryMobile will do the rest, including checking/unchecking.  You do not need to define any classes, such as ui-radio, ui-btn, etc.

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0 ">Check me
</label>
```

Documentation:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/checkboxradio-checkbox/

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3awV7/

Comment: It doesn't work because my html is being generated dynamically in jquery mobile

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Are you defining the checkbox via javascript and appending it to the page?